# How can I build custom rules using the output of workspace_status_command?

Tags: bazel

The `bazel build` flag `--workspace_status_command` supports calling a script to retrieve e.g. repository metadata, this is also known as build stamping and available in rules like `java_binary`.

I'd like to create a custom rule using this metadata.
I want to use this for a common support function. It should receive the git version and some other attributes and create a `version.go` output file usable as a dependency.

So I started a journey looking at rules in various bazel repositories.

Rules like `rules_docker` support stamping with `stamp` in `container_image` and let you reference the status output in attributes.

`rules_go` supports it in the `x_defs` attribute of `go_binary`.

This would be ideal for my purpose and I dug in...

It looks like I can get what I want with [`ctx.actions.expand_template`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#expand_template) using the entries in [`ctx.info_file` or `ctx.version_file`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/v0.4.0/container/image.bzl#L197) as a dictionary for `substitutions`. But I didn't figure out how to get a dictionary of those files. And those two files seem to be "unofficial", they are not part of the `ctx` documentation.

Building on what I found out already: How do I get a `dict` based on the status command output?

If that's not possible, what is the shortest/simplest way to access `workspace_status_command` output from custom rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been exactly where you are and I ended up following the path you've started exploring. I generate a JSON description that also includes information collected from git to package with the result and I ended up doing something like this:

```
def _build_mft_impl(ctx):
    args = ctx.actions.args()
    args.add('-f')
    args.add(ctx.info_file)
    args.add('-i')
    args.add(ctx.files.src)
    args.add('-o')
    args.add(ctx.outputs.out)
    ctx.actions.run(
        outputs = [ctx.outputs.out],
        inputs = ctx.files.src + [ctx.info_file],
        arguments = [args],
        progress_message = "Generating manifest: " + ctx.label.name,
        executable = ctx.executable._expand_template,
    )

def _get_mft_outputs(src):
    return {"out": src.name[:-len(".tmpl")]}

build_manifest = rule(
        implementation = _build_mft_impl,
        attrs = {
            "src": attr.label(mandatory=True,
                              allow_single_file=[".json.tmpl", ".json_tmpl"]),
            "_expand_template": attr.label(default=Label("//:expand_template"),
                                           executable=True,
                                           cfg="host"),
        },
        outputs = _get_mft_outputs,
    )
```

`//:expand_template` is a label in my case pointing to a `py_binary` performing the transformation itself. I'd be happy to learn about a better (more native, fewer hops) way of doing this, but (for now) I went with: it works. Few comments on the approach and your concerns:

- AFAIK you cannot read in (the file and perform operations in Skylark) itself...
- ...speaking of which, it's probably not a bad thing to keep the transformation (tool) and build description (bazel) separate anyways.
- It could be debated what constitutes the official documentation, but `ctx.info_file` may not appear in the reference manual, it is documented in the source tree. :) Which is case for other areas as well (and I hope that is not because those interfaces are considered not committed too yet).

---

For sake of comleteness in `src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/skylarkbuildapi/SkylarkRuleContextApi.java` there is:

```
@SkylarkCallable(
  name = "info_file",
  structField = true,
  documented = false,
  doc =
  "Returns the file that is used to hold the non-volatile workspace status for the "
      + "current build request."
)
public FileApi getStableWorkspaceStatus() throws InterruptedException, EvalException;
```

---

EDIT: few extra details as asked in the comment.

In my `workspace_status.sh` I would have for instance the following line:

```
echo STABLE_GIT_REF $(git log -1 --pretty=format:%H)
```

In my `.json.tmpl` file I would then have:

```
"ref": "${STABLE_GIT_REF}",
```

I've opted for shell like notation of text to be replaced, since it's intuitive for many users as well as easy to match.

As for the replacement, relevant (CLI kept out of this) portion of the actual code would be:

```
def get_map(val_file):
    """
    Return dictionary of key/value pairs from ``val_file`.
    """
    value_map = {}

    for line in val_file:
        (key, value) = line.split(' ', 1)
        value_map.update(((key, value.rstrip('\n')),))
    return value_map


def expand_template(val_file, in_file, out_file):
    """
    Read each line from ``in_file`` and write it to ``out_file`` replacing all
    ${KEY} references with values from ``val_file``.
    """
    def _substitue_variable(mobj):
        return value_map[mobj.group('var')]
    re_pat = re.compile(r'\${(?P<var>[^} ]+)}')
    value_map = get_map(val_file)
    for line in in_file:
        out_file.write(re_pat.subn(_substitue_variable, line)[0])
```

---

EDIT2: This is how the Python script is how I expose the python script to rest of bazel.

```
py_binary(
    name = "expand_template",
    main = "expand_template.py",
    srcs = ["expand_template.py"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Comment: I would have sworn there was a comment asking for a little more detail. I've sanitized the bits and kept the relevant parts and added it to the answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry. There was a comment. But I deleted it because I initially did not get the call to native Python and I did not address your solution correctly. Lacking edit rights, I deleted it. I'm currently experimenting with a genrule based on what you wrote - thanks for the update. If I'm getting anywhere, I'll add another answer.

Comment: No worries. I've also added a snippet from BUILD file that exposes the python script to the rest of the world (label used for `_expand_template` attributed of the rule above). I prefer to let bazel handle python as python. It's obvious what it is. And aids porting the build env. Those examples are bits of a larger package that use used as external dependency for project specific / custom packaging of build results. So, posting everything would probably be more confusing then helpful.

Comment: I hope my answer pays you back. Thanks for the amazing info!

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ondrej's answer, I now use somthing like this (adapted in SO editor, might contain small errors):

`tools/bazel.rc`:

```
build --workspace_status_command=tools/workspace_status.sh
```

`tools/workspace_status.sh`:

```
echo STABLE_GIT_REV $(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

`version.bzl`:

```
_VERSION_TEMPLATE_SH = """
set -e -u -o pipefail

while read line; do
  export "${line% *}"="${line#* }"
done <"$INFILE" \
&& cat <<EOF >"$OUTFILE"
{ "ref": "${STABLE_GIT_REF}"
, "service": "${SERVICE_NAME}"
}
EOF
"""

def _commit_info_impl(ctx):
  ctx.actions.run_shell(
      outputs = [ctx.outputs.outfile],
      inputs = [ctx.info_file],
      progress_message = "Generating version file: " + ctx.label.name,
      command = _VERSION_TEMPLATE_SH,
      env = {
        'INFILE': ctx.info_file.path,
        'OUTFILE': ctx.outputs.version_go.path,
        'SERVICE_NAME': ctx.attr.service,
      },
  )

commit_info = rule(
    implementation = _commit_info_impl,
    attrs = {
      'service': attr.string(
          mandatory = True,
          doc = 'name of versioned service',
      ),
    },
    outputs = {
      'outfile': 'manifest.json',
    },
)
```